# Get variable from line

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, grep

Hello I have got this line

`$ echo $(xinput | grep "TouchPad")
      SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=12 [slave pointer (2)]`

and I would like to ask if its possible to somehow get 12 and save it to variable. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to save to a variable: In what language (bash, perl, ...)?

Comment: In bash language

Comment: Note that you can also use `device='SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'` in the answer I gave to your other question (you don't need to use device ids when specifying a device for `xinput`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use this script/var in your machine , the device name will be the same all the time. Thus you can just do

```
$ xinput list --id-only "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
#Output:
12
```

To store it in a variable:

```
$ var=$(xinput list --id-only "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad")
```

Comment: Welcome. Remember that `man command` and `command --help` (replace command with the command you are interested in, i.e `xinput --help`) are your best friends

Answer (score 2):

```
device_id=$(xinput | sed -n 's/.*TouchPad.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p')
```

See [that other answer](/a/339498) for a description of that common `sed` idiom.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to get the device's numerical identifier, you can use the string directly. Use `xinput list --name-only | grep Touchpad` to list device names that contain “Touchpad”, one per line.

If you do want the numerical identifier, call `xinput list` again, this time with `--id-only`.

```
name=$(xinput list --name-only | grep Touchpad)
nl='
'
case "$name" in
  *"$nl"*) echo "Multiple touchpad devices found, aborting"; exit 2;;
  "") echo "No touchpad device found, aborting"; exit 2;;
esac
id=$(xinput list --id-only "$name")
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward, if not the most efficient, way is:

```
deviceid="$(xinput | grep "TouchPad" | grep -oE 'id=[^ ]+' | cut -d= -f2)"
```

You can then refer to `"$deviceid"` in your script(s).

Working forward to see how this works, I first take the command you started with to get the line of input to parse.  I then use `grep -o`, which returns only the matched data rather than the entire line, and `-E`, which allows for a more succinct syntax.  The expression `/id=[^ ]+/` means "an `i`, a `d`, an `=` symbol, and one or more characters which are *not* a space.  This extracts `id=12`.  I then send that to `cut`, which I tell to split the input at `=` symbols (with the `-d` (for **d**elimiter) switch), and take the second field, which is the `12` you wanted.

This is all run in a subshell, the output of which is used as the value of the variable.

Comment: Much thanks could you please add explanation for each command

Comment: Excuse me but actually the output is "12 [slave" not straight "12"

Comment: `$ cat input  | grep -Eo -e 'TouchPad.*' | grep -Eo 'id=[^ ]+' | cut -d= -f2` yields `12`